# Do math inside a SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, math, pdo, timestamp

I'm trying to make it so I can select values that are below 601 (slightly 10 minutes). I take `time()` and subtract it by the field `time`. I don't understand why it isn't working. Can someone explain or does SQL just not have this ability. I don't get any error, though it gives data that doesn't make much sense.

```
$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `online` WHERE '".time()."'-`time` > 601");
```

It doesn't seem to be working.

**Database**

[image: Database]

**Sample Data**

`id` = 1

`uid` = 1

`time` = 1376252614 (To be honest, I don't know why this is a `TEXT`. I haven't had an issue with it before though, so that's why I assume that it's not the problem)

Comment: Check a basis: `"SELECT '".time()."' - online.time AS t FROM online` - does what? (First identify *what* is going on.)

Comment: Are you using MySQL? SQL Server?

Comment: Please disclose your table structure.

Comment: I added my structure to the main post

Comment: If you can, please change the type of `time` (or whatever the eventual name) to a timestamp (best) or at least a long (would at least allow use of an index/math).  Text is just shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in MySQL and your `time` column is a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` data type, try this query.

```
WHERE `time` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 601 SECOND
```

If your `time` column is an integer containing a Unix-style timestamp (or a text string showing an integer), then try this.

```
WHERE `time` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 601
```

This way of structuring the query allows MySQL to exploit an index on your `time` column. But, if the timestamp's a text string the index will work a little strangely.

Notice that `time` is a suboptimal choice for a column name because it's a MySQL reserved word.  You have to be diligent to enclose it in backticks all the time, or you'll get bizarre errors.

Comment: I'll change the name if I have to. Thank you, this worked! The second one is what I tried, and it did ended up working.

Comment: Please consider using an integer or TIMESTAMP data type.  Indexes on text strings sometimes yield unpredictable results if you're comparing integers.

Comment: ... Is it converting the text column to integer, then? Which would imply that it's converting every row (and ignoring the index); otherwise I'd have expected it to sort `'2'` _after_ `'11'`, stuff like that.  And it might not be a worry here (timestamps imply log values) but negative values do weird things to sorting too.

Comment: Yes, there's an implicit conversion of text to integer when doing arithmetic on text fields. And you're exactly right about '2' coming after '11'.  Plus, the implicit conversion defeats indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you're wanting to do is the following:

```
pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `online` WHERE ADDTIME(time, '0 0:10:0') > NOW()")
```

This is one way of achieving your goal with MySQL, there are other functions, this is just the first one I saw that fit my need.

This method will add 10 minutes to your time and then compare it against the current time, if it's greater than the current time then it means it happened within the last 10 minutes.

Comment: Tags (currently) state MySQL (correct or not).  Please update your answer for that platform.  You are heading in the right direction, though  (making the condition SARGable).

Comment: You are correct, my mistake, I've updated the answer @Clockwork-Muse

Comment: Your condition is no longer SARGable, and will ignore any index `time` might have (this is assuming that `time` is actually a date/time type, and not text; ironically, if `ADDTIME()` converts the string to a date/time value, the results should be correct, which may not be the case for the SARGable version...).